# Launching an external Java class after a particular condition

Tags: java

I have two java class files, say A and B. Is there any way I can run B from A (this is because I want to check some condition in A and when satisfied run B)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as classes `A` and `B` are in the classpath, running the `main` method of class `B` from `A` could be as simple as:

```
if (condition)
{
  String args = new String[] {"arguments", "for", "B"};
  B.main(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's a method in class B that you want to run, you can set it as public.  Then in class A, instantiate class B and call it.

```
//class B
public void doSomething()
{
//do something
}

//class A

B friendlyName = new B();
If (condition)
{
    friendlyName.doSomething();
}
```

Have a great day:)
Patrick.